# Rails 3 select_tag not producing DOM elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm trying to use a `select_tag` helper in Rails 3. I started with a very basic example, copied straight [from the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag):

It seems to produce the correct markup, but the select doesn't work - clicking it does nothing.

For comparison, I created the same select in HAML. **That works fine.** Here is the code for both:

```
-# The select_tag version
= select_tag "count", "<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>"

-# The HAML version
%select{:name => "count", :id => "count"}
  %option 1
  %option 2
  %option 3
  %option 4
```

The `select_tag` seems to produce the options in a string, but not as DOM elements - in Firebug, they are just gray, not syntax-highlighted like the DOM elements in the working select produced by HAML.

What's the deal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the answer just before I posted the question: **the string needs to have .html_safe called on it.**

Viewing source shows that Rails has turned all the `<` and `>` into `&lt;` and `&gt;`, because it's now escaping strings by default. `html_safe` says "no really, trust me, this one is OK to display as HTML."

So this makes it work:

```
= select_tag "count", "<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>".html_safe
```

It would be nice if they updated the documentation, but hey, at least the answer is quickly searchable here now. :)

Comment: Another tip: make sure the *whole* string you're passing in for options is .html_safe - for ex, if you're calling `string1 + some_array.map{}.join().html_safe`, it won't work because .html_safe is only called on the last expression. Place it in parens, or use `raw()` around the whole thing instead (equivalent).